# Is there an alternative to Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick for touch-enabled excel?

Tags: vb.net, excel, windows-8, touch

I am trying to make an ancient excel based application (with macros) work on an windows 8 touchscreen device. Unfortunately `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` and `Worksheet_BeforeRightClick` are not firing when touched - mouse actions are firing like they always did though.

Are there alternatives for these events or is there a known workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, if you touch a worksheet, you change a selection. Have you tried **Worksheet_SelectionChange** event?